# Dúvidas sobre integração boleto Bradesco

Tags: php, laravel, xml, cakephp, soap

Estou com dúvida sobre como integrar essa solução de pagamentos Bradesco.
Essa é a [documentação](http://mupteste.comercioeletronico.com.br/sepsManager/Download/Versao3/Guia%20de%20integracao%20Boleto%20Bancario.pdf)

Não sei se é via POST, via GET, se é via XML. estou confuso..
tentei algo assim

```
<?php

 $adm = '0000';
 $order = '1';
 $url = "http://mupteste.comercioeletronico.com.br/sepsBoleto/".$adm."/prepara_pagto.asp?merchantid=".$adm."&orderid=".$order."&numOrder=".$order;

 if($_GET){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_GET);
 }
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $url  ?>">
    <input type="hidden" value="1"      name="orderid">
    <input type="hidden" value="dasdad" name="descritivo">
    <input type="hidden" value="1"      name="quantidade">
    <input type="hidden" value="UN"     name="unidade">
    <input type="hidden" value="150"    name="valor">
    <input type="hidden" value="150"    name="valor">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

mas não tenho sucesso

Comment: A sua própria "[Documentação](http://mupteste.comercioeletronico.com.br/sepsManager/Download/Versao3/Guia%20de%20integracao%20Boleto%20Bancario.pdf)" mostra o que deve ser feito, passo a passo e ainda disponibiliza meios de suporte, basta entrar em contato como mostra na última página do manual.